# Angular2 NGRX/Store View Not Updating

Tags: angular, typescript, view, store, ngrx

Sorry for yet another Angular 2 view update question but I haven't been able to find an answer in any other responses. I'm mentioning the use of NGRX/Store here though I doubt its the reason the view isn't updating.Oddly enough it seems to update once (at least) but manages to stay a step behind. The last (most recent) update never takes affect. When the model updates, the previous state updates in the view. It's mind boggling really. Heres the appropriate code.

**Relevant Installed packages**

```
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.0.1",
```

**My main app module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        ConsumerApp,
        AppManagement,
        MyApps,
        AppRegistration,
        AppDetails,
    ],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        STORE_PROVIDERS,
        AppManagementService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        ConsumerApp
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**My-Apps Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-apps',
    template: require('./templates/my-apps.html')
})
export class MyApps implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    apps = {};
    change = 1;
    userAppsSubscription;

    constructor (
        private appsService: AppManagementService,
        private store: Store<any> ) {}

    ngOnInit () {

        this.userAppsSubscription = this.store
            .select('userApps')
            .subscribe( userApps => {
                this.apps = Object.assign(this.apps, userApps);
                this.change++;
                console.log(this);
            })

        this.appsService.getUserApps();
    }

    ngOnDestroy () {

        this.userAppsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**My-Apps template**

```
<div id="my-apps">
    <h1>My Apps</h1>
    <h2>{{change}}</h2>
    <p>You currently don't have any registered applications. Click "Register an App" to get started.</p>

    <p [hidden]="!loading">{{apps | json}}</p>

    <div class="apps-container">  
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let app of apps.available">
            <button class="block-button">
                <h3>{{app.name}}</h3>
                <p><strong>Description:</strong> {{app.description}}</p>  
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**App Management Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppManagementService {

    constructor (
        private http: Http, 
        private store: Store<any>) {}

    getUserApps () {

        this.store
            .dispatch({
                type: RETRIEVE_USER_APPS,
                payload: null
            })

        return this.http
            .get(ALL_APPS)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                this.store
                    .dispatch({
                        type: RECIEVE_USER_APPS,
                        payload: response.json()
                    })
            })
            .catch(response => {
                this.store
                    .dispatch({
                        type: RETRIEVAL_FAILURE_USER_APPS,
                        payload: null
                    })
            });
    }
}
```

**When the "My Apps" page is first hit this is what end up being printed out.**

[image]

**And this is where the view end up.**

[image]

Odd right? you can see the page was updated with the second state broadcasted from the NGRX/Store but not the final state Which contains the real bread and butter (the list of 6 apps). Why on earth would the view not update properly?

Comment: Did you figured it out ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your reducer?

I would refactor this to not unwrap the stream in the Init method. Use the async pipe to do this for you. This also handles the unsubscribe.

Something like:

HTML

```
<div id="my-apps">
    <h1>My Apps</h1>
    <h2>{{change}}</h2>
    <p>You currently don't have any registered applications. Click "Register an App" to get started.</p>

    <p [hidden]="!loading">{{apps | json}}</p>

    <div class="apps-container">  
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let app of ($userAppsSubscription | async).apps.available">
            <button class="block-button">
                <h3>{{app.name}}</h3>
                <p><strong>Description:</strong> {{app.description}}</p>  
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-apps',
    template: require('./templates/my-apps.html')
})
export class MyApps implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    apps = {};
    change = 1;
    $userAppsSubscription:Observable<string>;

    constructor (
        private appsService: AppManagementService,
        private store: Store<any> ) {}

    ngOnInit () {

        this.userAppsSubscription = this.store
            .select('userApps');

        this.appsService.getUserApps();
    }

    ngOnDestroy () {

        this.userAppsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```